# facebook graph api - App-to-User Notifications

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

i used Facebook graph API for sending notification to Facebook from my website , I used p-h-p code in it . it working perfectly on desktop site , but when i open Facebook from my android/iPhone phone , notification is not displaying.

i tried all open that provided by  Facebook app notifications doc.

but its not working please somebody help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The notifications are only surfaced on the desktop web version of Facebook

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/appnotifications